# Is there a tool to manage elasticsearch migration

Tags: elasticsearch

I just started with `ElasticSearch` and I wish to automate migration between code versions.

For `RDBMS` I use tools like [phinx](https://phinx.org/) that apply changes to the DB.

For example:

1. Create a migration file with up() & down() methods.
2. Write commands to apply (for example add index).
3. after tests and etc `./phinx migrate`.

Is there a migration tool like this?

If not, is there another acceptable approach to handle changes to the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of a tool like that specifically for ES indexes.

If your goal is to update the internal representation of your data, i think the best approach is just create a script that:

- Find the affected documents
- Read the contents
- Modify them
- Reindex them in a new doc
- Then you can delete the old document.

Update a doc it wont be more efficient that reindex, since documents are immutable, so update is just get + reindex (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html)

Comment: Its not exactly update. Its a version control manager. Its suppose to know the current DB version and run the right migrate scripts one by one in an orderly manner.

Answer (score 0):

Flyway with code-based (e.g. Java) migrations can be used to work with any data store. Similar to migrating relational DB, but requires a bit more work since you need to implement calls to ElasticSearch with the relevant commands (e.g. create index).

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations.html#java-based-migrations

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a background of RDBMS, the migration tool is very handy when you are working with a big project that is having a lot of migrations files. I was also facing the same issue with Elasticsearch that currently there was no stable migration tool in the community.

I have created a migration tool and it will be handy if you are coming from a background of python https://pypi.org/project/chalan/. The core idea is taken from Alembic migration tool that is for Sqlalchemy.

Usage is simple

```
pip install chalan
```

Then for upgrade you have to use

```
chalan upgrade
```

And for downgrade you have to use

```
chalan downgrade
```

Please let me know if you face any issues with this tool and feel free to suggest some improvements if any.

For source code please refer the github link - https://github.com/anandtripathi5/chalan